# Why isn't the "Add Email" feature working with my updated E-mail address?

Tags: activities, outlook, salesforce-for-outlook

I changed E-mail addresses, and my new E-mail address was updated in Salesforce. Now, when using the "send and add (E-mail)" feature in Outlook, I get the following error message:

"This message was created automatically by the mail system.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

> > > emailtosalesforce@4-3e6nkvm385attenipo61n93mh.3-9syeaq.5.le.salesforce.com (Undelivered): 551 Failed due to: SenderAuthorization

------ This is a copy of the original message, including all headers. ------

Return-Path: 
X-SFDC-Original-RCPT: emailtosalesforce@4-3e6nkvm385attenipo61n93mh.3-9syeaq.5.le.salesforce.com
X-SFDC-Binding: coremailprocessor
X-SFDC-DOMAINKEYS: None
X-SFDC-TLS-VERIFIED: no
X-SFDC-TLS-CIPHER: DES-CBC3-SHA
X-SFDC-TLS-STATUS: true
X-SFDC-SENDERID-PRA: Pass
X-SFDC-SENDERID: Pass
X-SFDC-SPF: Pass
X-SFDC-Interface: external
Received: from [173.203.6.128] ([173.203.6.128:60674] helo=smtp128.ord.emailsrvr.com)
by mx4-asg.mta.salesforce.com (envelope-from )
(ecelerity 2.2.2.45 r()) with ESMTPS (cipher=DES-CBC3-SHA) 
id 02/E0-02045-E3D93125; Tue, 20 Aug 2013 16:45:51 +0000
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by smtp25.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id B15553F0603
for ; Tue, 20 Aug 2013 12:45:49 -0400 (EDT)
X-Virus-Scanned: OK
Received: from smtp192.mex05.mlsrvr.com (unknown [184.106.31.85])
by smtp25.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTPS id DD2933F0967
for ; Tue, 20 Aug 2013 12:45:48 -0400 (EDT)
Received: from ORD2MBX03E.mex05.mlsrvr.com ([fe80::92e2:baff:fe20:c3a8]) by
ORD2HUB22.mex05.mlsrvr.com ([fe80::be30:5bff:feee:1a6c%15]) with mapi id
14.03.0123.003; Tue, 20 Aug 2013 11:45:46 -0500
From: Emily Roberson McCoy 
To: "ghuhta@tza.com" 
Subject: Content Creation recap
Thread-Topic: Content Creation recap
Thread-Index: Ac6dxK4CHb7E4j6yTAa8aqqbvrbzUw==
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 16:45:46 +0000
Message-ID: <38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1@ORD2MBX03E.mex05.mlsrvr.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-originating-ip: [24.153.230.26]
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="_007_38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1ORD2MBX03Emex05ml_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_007_38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1ORD2MBX03Emex05ml_
Content-Type: multipart/related;
boundary="_006_38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1ORD2MBX03Emex05ml_";
type="multipart/alternative"

--_006_38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1ORD2MBX03Emex05ml_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="_000_38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1ORD2MBX03Emex05ml_"

--_000_38F4C991E8F4FB409A9E740B03472FDB9EB5F1ORD2MBX03Emex05ml_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

(abridged)"

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you whitelist the new email address in your Salesforce email preferences? Go to `My Name | Setup` or `Setup | My Settings` and then select `Email | Email to Salesforce`. Verify your new email address is in the field `Acceptable Email Addresses`.